# Back button duplicating ajax requests on view load

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-views, backbone-routing

**Edit**

I put a console.log in the fetch success callback of the home view (#/). These are the cid ids of the fetches each time the page loaded. You can see by the end there are 6 fetch requests being made when on the original page load there is only one.

```
/#: c2  
/#link1 + back button: c4, c2  
/#link1 + back button: c4, c2, c2, c2  
/#link2 + back button: c4, c2, c2, c2, c2, c2
```

**Original**

I'm experiencing an odd bug in backbone where the back button is causing ajax requests to duplicate. If I go to `#/` then click on `#/link` both of those make their ajax requests fine. The problem is when I hit the back button to go back to `#/`. It makes the normal ajax requests but twice. If I repeat the process each time I hit the back button it increased the number of duplicate requests (1 original + number of back buttons): 2 back button pushes = 3 ajax requests, 3 back button pushes = 4 ajax requests

Even when I go to a completely different link (after I've used back button) on the view it duplicates that view's ajax requests. If I just click links and don't use the back button, the bug never happens.

I'm using AppView in the router to clean up the old view and load the new view. This calls Backbone.View.prototype.close which in turns calls View.close. I think this is all sound but wanted to include just in case.

Has any experienced this before?

**AppView**

```
function AppView () {
  this.view = null;

  this.showView = function (view, renderOpts) {
    renderOpts = (typeof renderOpts === 'undefined') ? {} : renderOpts;

    if (this.view) this.view.close();

    this.view = view;

    $('.view').html(this.view.render(renderOpts).el);
  }
}
```

**Backbone.View.prototype.close**

```
Backbone.View.prototype.close = function () {
  this.remove();
  this.unbind();

  if (this.onClose) this.onClose();
};
```

**Router**

```
var Router = Backbone.Router.extend({
  routes: {
    '': 'home',
    'compound_interests/new': 'editCompoundInterest',
    'compound_interests/:id': 'viewCompoundInterest',
    'compound_interests/:id/parameters': 'compoundInterestParametersEditor',
    'compound_interests/:id/test': 'compoundInterestTester',
    'compound_interests/:id/stream': 'compoundInterestStreamer'
  },
  initialize: function (opts) {
    this.appView = opts.appView;
  },
  home: function () {
    var view = new HomeView();
    this.appView.showView(view);
  },
  editCompoundInterest: function () {
    var view = new EditCompoundInterestView();
    this.appView.showView(view);
  },
  viewCompoundInterest: function (id) {
    var view = new ViewCompoundInterestView({ id: id });
    this.appView.showView(view);
  },
  compoundInterestParametersEditor: function (id) {
    var view = new CompoundInterestParametersEditorView({ id: id });
    this.appView.showView(view);
  },
  compoundInterestTester: function (id) {
    var view = new CompoundInterestTesterView({ id: id });
    this.appView.showView(view);
  },
  compoundInterestStreamer: function (id) {
    var view = new CompoundInterestStreamerView({ id: id });
    this.appView.showView(view);
  }
});

router = new Router({ appView: new AppView() });
```

**Home View**

```
var Backbone = require('backbone'),
    _ = require('lodash');

var CompoundInterests = require('../collections/compound_interests');

module.exports = Backbone.View.extend({
  initialize: function () {
    var that = this;

    _.bindAll(this, 'render');

    this.template = JST['templates/home'];
    this.context = { data: {} };

    this.compoundInterests = new CompoundInterests();
    this.compoundInterests.on('sync', this.render);
    this.compoundInterests.fetch();
  },
  onClose: function () {
    this.compoundInterests.off('sync');
    this.render();
  },
  render: function () {
    this.context.data.compoundInterests = _.clone(this.compoundInterests.models);
    this.$el.html(this.template(this.context));
    return this;
  }
});
```

Comment: `unbind` is the old method name for `Events.off` and when you call `this.remove` it will remove events you have bound with `listenTo` anyway so I don't think you need it. Have you tried putting in a `debugger` statement in initialize where you are doing the fetch (or in `compoundInterests.fetch`) and checking the call stack and also checking if the multiple fetches have different `this.cid`'s - meaning you have multiple views? It's not obvious why it's going wrong from the code you posted. Also fyi `renderOpts = renderOpts || {};` is shorter.